# MyBatis - returning empty value when IN operator is used

Tags: ibatis, mybatis

I have a query like below,

```
<select id="getTableName" resultType="java.lang.String" parameterType="java.lang.String">
    Select Distinct TableName From TABLE_COLUMN_MAPPING Where COLUMNNAME IN (#{columnNames})
</select>
```

am calling the service method by passing the values as below.

```
sampleService.getTableName("'BANKRM','APPLICANTID','APPLICANTTYPE','APPLICANTTYPE','TOTAL','SCQUES9'");
```

but its returning... [ ]

Help me why am not getting values instead am getting empty List.

P.S: I checked the log and its statements are created with out any issues

```
2013-03-22 19:16:27,521 DEBUG [main] org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource (debug:27) - Created connection 23845098.
2013-03-22 19:16:27,590 DEBUG [main] java.sql.Connection (debug:27) - ooo Connection Opened
2013-03-22 19:16:27,670 DEBUG [main] java.sql.PreparedStatement (debug:27) - ==>  Executing: Select Distinct TableName From Config_FieldDetails Where COLUMNNAME IN (?) 
2013-03-22 19:16:27,670 DEBUG [main] java.sql.PreparedStatement (debug:27) - ==> Parameters: 'BANKRM','APPLICANTID','APPLICANTTYPE','APPLICANTTYPE','TOTAL','SCQUES9'(String)
2013-03-22 19:16:27,954 DEBUG [main] java.sql.Connection (debug:27) - xxx Connection Closed
2013-03-22 19:16:27,955 DEBUG [main] org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource (debug:27) - Returned connection 23845098 to pool.
2013-03-22 19:16:27,955 INFO [main] com.hcl.cob.mybatis.bpm.service.impl.COBBPMCommonServiceImpl (getTableNameFromConfigFieldDetails:41) - getTableNameFromConfigFieldDetails(String columnName) -- End
```

Comment: This is not good query. You cant add part of query as parameter of `PreparedStatement`. You are trying to add part of query, not parameter. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the list of column names in one List parameter and then pass that to the query:

```
List<String> columnNames = Arrays.asList(["BANKRM", "APPLICANTID", "APPLICANTTYPE", "APPLICANTTYPE","TOTAL","SCQUES9"]); 
sampleService.getTableName(columnNames);
```

Then update the query to take a list and use the `foreach` tag to iterate over the list values and put them in the `in` clause:

```
<select id="getTableName" resultType="java.lang.String" parameterType="java.util.List">
    Select Distinct TableName From TABLE_COLUMN_MAPPING Where COLUMNNAME IN 
        <foreach item="columnName" index="index" collection="columnNames" open="(" separator="," close=")">
            #{columnName}
        </foreach>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanx @clav will check out this solution on monday and get back, hope this will help...

Comment: @clav, the below error am getting,
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.mapping.SqlMapperException: The expression 'columnNames' evaluated to a null value.

Comment: Are you using a mapper? You should have a mapper interface that defines the parameters used by the query and your service will call the mapper method to execute the query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put parameter which will be used to create `PreparedStatement` (not to pass parameter), you should use `${}` notation:

```
${columnNames}
```

Comment: I think $ should be used when the parameterType is map. the # working fine for other queries, Its not working for this.

Comment: No it is used to create string for query, not to pass parameter to prepared statement. Did you tried with `$`? See **String
Substitution** part of MyBatis reference.

Comment: Can you please provide more info for not working? Stack trace is not when `$` is used.